# Showing window at x,y of the button cell in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a outline view with a custom cell class, my cell.
In Every Cell I am adding a NSButton. On Click of the Button I wish to show a window.

Now my problem is that the button coordinates are relative to the contentView it drawn in.
And a window to be displayed should be with absolute coordinates.

One more observation if I draw window at 0,0 the window is drawn at the lower left corner of the screen.

How to map the cell coordinates to absolute so that i can display the window just after the button

please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [NSTableView's frameOfCellAtColumn:row:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/frameOfCellAtColumn%3arow%3a)?

Comment: I have a button cell in the outline view. Outline view does not have frameOfRow

Comment: It inherits it from NSTableView.